# Can I build Azure Managed Image from other Azure Managed Image with packer

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, packer

I'd like to build custom azure managed image using packer. But some steps for provisioning are needed GUI operation. I tried make base image as azure managed image.

Now I have Azure Managed Image like

/subscriptions//resourceGroups//providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/

Can I build custom image from Azure Managed Image using packer?

Comment: I'd like to build images windows server 2008 R2 ~ 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different variation on 'packer imager' out there but **Azure VM Image Builder** which is still in private preview should do exactly what you are trying to do.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-private-preview-of-azure-vm-image-builder/

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer.md

Comment: Yes but Azure VM Image Builder support Windows Server 2016 or later...
I need build all supported OS (2008 R2 - 2019)